# Java Spring requires some EE features in Tomcat. Is Spring a Jakarta EE framework?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I spent the last few days trying to wrap my head around the Java ecosystem, looking at the components (JVM, JRE, JDK, SE, EE, etc.), licensing and others.

As far as I understand, Jakarta EE (formerly Java EE, J2EE) is an API on top of Java SE with lots of enterprise-grade features and lots of (mostly deprecated) web technologies. Spring has similar goals but a different approach and runs on "standard" Java SE.

But then what about Tomcat? Tomcat is defined as an implementation of Jakarta EE features. I understand that TomEE is a "superset" of Tomcat with more Jakarta EE features.

Nevertheless, Spring (needs / requires) Tomcat as a runtime. Does that mean that Spring uses Jakarta EE features? Could you please clarify these differences?

Comment: Spring MVC requires a J2EE container to run (not necessarily Tomcat).

Comment: @Olivier Spring only requires a Servlet container to run, not a full Jakarta EE container (J2EE is already two names ago for the specification).

Comment: @Olivier OK thanks, that's what I realized. "Needing a J2EE container", so it does mean that Spring uses (part of) the J2EE API?

Comment: Yes, Spring uses the Servlet API, which is part of Java EE.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Could you elaborate a bit? As I understand Servlets are part of the J EE API

Comment: Yes, the servlet specification is **part** of Jakarta EE, but Tomcat isn't a full implementation of Jakarta EE. It is (only) a servlet container, but not a full Jakarta EE application server.

Answer (score 3):

Tomcat 10 offers JakartaEE, but no JEE.
Versions lower than 10 implement JEE but no JakartaEE.  [Here's the overview](https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html)

To my knowledge, spring works on JEE, but not JakartaEE (at the time of writing this answer). So if you want to use *tomcat* with spring,  pick version 9 (as of today), or another JEE container.

Comment: Tomcat 9 does offer JakartaEE, version 8, while Tomcat 10 is JakartaEE version 9. Version 9 is the JakartaEE version that changed the package namespace from `javax` to `jakarta`.

Comment: If i understand you answer correctly, you would confirm that Spring uses/works on Java EE, through Tomcat which is an implementation. My question mentioned Jakarta EE, no say JEE, etc, but that's just a question of version (that might be important), but in the end this is confusing again...

Comment: Yes, Spring (versions up to 5.3 as of today, but not 6) and Sprint Boot (versions 1 and 2, but not 3) depend on JEE (renamed to Jakarta EE 8 few years ago) API. Spring 6 and Spring Boot 3, released late 2022, require Jakarta EE 9 and are not backward compatible with JEE… Same with Tomcat - 10 goes with new Spring, everything older with old Spring.

Answer (score 2):

Spring does not implement most of the JakartaEE/JavaEE specification. One of the Spring project that implements a JSR defined in JavaEE that I can think of is spring-batch (see [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/jsr-352.html)).

Instead, Spring mainly provides support to integrate with a carefully selected individual specifications from JavaEE to allow developers to work with the implementation of these specifications using the Spring programming model (See [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/overview.html#overview-history) for more detail.)

Tomcat is the implementation of the Servlet API which is one of the specification that is included in JakartaEE/JavaEE. To me , the most useful and modern support provided by Spring for it is spring-boot allows to package the application using an embeddable Tomcat such that we can simply deploy and run the application as a JAR without install a Tomcat server separately and deploy the WAR to it.

Answer (score 0):

Spring does not necessarily require tomcat. It depends on your use-case, and in fact, Spring Boot uses Netty out of the box, but allows for the use of Tomcat as well.

Spring is a DI framework which allows for extensibility through its many optional libraries. Its main goal is to allow you to program in a more modular way using the DI paradigm, improving upon OOP and mitigating some of its disadvantages, mainly allowing for separation of concerns.

Depending on your use-case, you may not use Jakarta libraries at all.

To read more about SOLID principles:
https://www.baeldung.com/solid-principles